# django queryset convert tofixed format

Tags: django, django-queryset

i am using django frame work .fetching the value from postgresql database.
 my queryset is:

```
       pp=childcrime_type.objects.values('infanticide_incidence').filter(state_name='GUJARAT')
```

my queryset is in decimal format.how to convert decimal format queryset to tofixed foramt.

```
    [13.9,12.4,9.6,3,41.3,5.8,36]
```

but i have answer in following format.

```
    [13.90,12.40,09.60,03.00,41.30,05.80,36.00]

Thanks
```

Comment: Are you using Decimalfield or Floatfield for data ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really make sense.
The data will be stored in the list as it currently . 
What you seem to be asking is how you should display it with 2 decimal places accuracy

This will create the list of strings you are looking for:

```
map(
    lambda(x): "%0.2f" % round(x,2),
    pp,
)
```

How you display this list is up to you. But however you display the list doesn't change the underlying data in the list pp at all